# AudioGraph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync resulting in FormatNotSupported with wav and AudioNodeEmitter

Tags: audio, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm trying out the new spatial audio functions in the AudioGraph 1.1 API and I have sound output from a file working without an emitter, but when I add an emitter to my node creation call it suddenly returns FormatNotSupported. I can't find any information via searching that has been any sort of helpful, probably because it's such a new API. Can anyone see if I'm doing something wrong or missing something? Following is my code:

```
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
            var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
            CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
            if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
            {
                return;
            }
            graph = result.Graph;

            FileOpenPicker saveFilePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            saveFilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
            saveFilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
            saveFilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            StorageFile file = await saveFilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            AudioNodeEmitter emitter = new AudioNodeEmitter(AudioNodeEmitterShape.CreateOmnidirectional(),
                AudioNodeEmitterDecayModel.CreateNatural(.1,1,10,100),
                AudioNodeEmitterSettings.None);
            emitter.Position = new Vector3(10, 0, 5);

            CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
            var outputNode = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;

            CreateAudioFileInputNodeResult fileInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(file, emitter);
            inputNode = fileInputNodeResult.FileInputNode;

            inputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(outputNode);
            graph.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code, problem is:

> Audio node emitters can only process audio that is formatted in mono with a sample rate of 48kHz. Attempting to use stereo audio or audio with a different sample rate will result in an exception.

You can refer to the note part of [Spatial audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#spatial-audio).

To test this API, you may download this [audio here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/GZ05/samples/tone.wav).

Comment: Thanks! I saw "for best performance" from the example I was looking at, didn't realise it was required. I have it playing audio now but making changes to y and z position doesn't seem to do anything to the sound (i.e. changing from -70 to 70 while sound is playing makes no difference). Are there any requirements for the headphones besides binaural sound?

Comment: Is it maybe just hard to hear the difference because I don't have a way to change the relative position of the emitter to the listener dynamically?

Comment: @Ceshion, it's possible, to be honestly, I'm not quite sure about this.